# Why hasn't this user's reputation increased?

Tags: discussion, reputation, faq-proposed

Recently, user **[Mark](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/5396/mark)** has posted an answer to the question: "[Why doesn't water burn?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64362/why-doesnt-h2o-burn/64372)"
and it has got a score of 78 as of now this meta question has been posted. So, if an upvote of an answer increases your reputation by 10, logically he should have got **780** reputation. But still now, he has **473** reputation. Why is this so?

The following is a snapshot of a part of the timeline of reputation of user Mark:

[image]

([I put the link here to examine this case](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/5396/mark?tab=reputation))

He has got +10 reputation points for upvotes upto 7:37 AM, 12/13/2016(yesterday) and from onwards he didn't get reputation for his upvotes though he got reputation points on upvotes today (i.e 12/14/2016). Why is this so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A user can gain a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Reputation from accepts, association bonuses, and bounties are exempt from this cap.

This is outlined in the [help centre](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

See also: [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)

Therefore, the first 20 upvotes earned Mark 200 reputation yesterday. The other 41 upvotes that happened yesterday gave him no reputation.

Comment: Happily for me, all of those excess upvotes *do* still count toward tag badges.